# Angularjs: ngView not rendering view in jade

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to angularjs and working on project where is need to use `ngView` with jade for rendering views. I have also searched through the previous questions asked about `ngView` here but couldn't find anything helpful. The issue I'm facing is whenever I use `ngView` as an attribute of div in jade it compiles the jade template and shows the compiled HTML like:-

```
 <div ng-controller='ArticleListCtrl'>

    <!-- ngView:  -->

 </div>
```

The jade template is:-

```
div(ng-controller='ArticleListCtrl')

  div(ng-view)
```

The route using config function in my app.js is:-

```
var nodeApp = angular.module("nodeApp",["ngRoute"]);

nodeApp.config(['$locationProvider','$routeProvider',function($locationProvider,$routeProvider){

    $routeProvider

        .when('/',{

            templateUrl: 'articles/art.html',

            controller: 'ArticleListCtrl'
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

So, can anybody help me or point me in right direction if I'm doing something wrong?

This is the complete jade template:-

```
doctype html

html(ng-app='nodeApp' lang='en')

  include ../includes/head

  body

    div(ng-controller='ArticleListCtrl')

      div(ng-view)
```

And this is compiled html generated from the jade template above:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="ng-scope" lang="en" ng-app="nodeApp">

    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# nodejsexpressdemo: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/nodejsexpressdemo#"></head>

    <body>

        <div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="ArticleListCtrl">

            <!-- ngView:  -->

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to paste some html in your ng-view div, and see what happens, I mean 

"div(ng-view) foo"

Comment: I tried with putting p tag in it and it shows nothing in compiled Html. Also, I have mentioned the whole jade template and its compiled html above.